# como executar essa curl no php?

Tags: php, api, libcurl, erp

Tenho essa Curl `curl -s https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/pesquisartitulos/ -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"call":"PesquisarLancamentos","app_key":"XXXXXXXXX","app_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","param":[{"nPagina":1,"nRegPorPagina":12,"cCPFCNPJCliente":"XXXXXXXXXX","cNatureza":"R","cStatus":"EMABERTO"}]}'` e não consigo passar esses parametros na execução dela no php. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$ch = curl_init();
        ;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/pesquisartitulos/");
  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['call' => 'PesquisarLancamentos', 'app_key' => 'XXXXXXXXX','app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        // Visualizar resultado:
        var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aparentemente faltou setar o header `Content-Type` e fazer o encode dos campos.

Fiz esse exemplo usando a `curl_setopt_array`, acredito que irá resolver o seu problema.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/pesquisartitulos/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['call' => 'PesquisarLancamentos', 'app_key' => 'XXXXXXXXX','app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX']),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'Content-type: application/json'
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, precisei acrescentar outras linhas e vou deixar o código abaixo de como ficou. Porém não consigo exibir no html ...

Comment: Que maravilha que funcionou. Qual o problema pra exibir? A resposta do curl é um HTML?

Comment: Tentei colocar o resultado em um foreach para pegar apenas o numero do bolteo e não consegui. Consegui apenas esse resultado:    'string(1157) "{"nPagina":1,"nTotPaginas":1,"nRegistros":1,"nTotRegistros":1,"titulosEncontrados":[{"cabecTitulo":{"aCodCateg":[{"cCodCateg":"1.01.02","nPerc":100,"nValor":700}],"cCPFCNPJCliente":"47.666.904\/0001-14","cCodCateg":"1.01.02","cCodIntTitulo":"","cCodVendedor":3729265544,"cCodigoBarras":"34191.09008 00069.070696 59960.330005 6 90470000070000","cNatureza":"R" ... '

Comment: usei o foarech errado.. por isso não deu certo.

Comment: Show. Então se seu problema foi resolvido, peço que se possível escolha uma das respostas =] e se tiver alguma dúvida ainda é só falar aqui

Comment: comi bola, não deu certo.. Estou usando o foreach assim: 'foreach ($response->titulosEncontrados as $api) {
                var_dump($api);
            }'

Comment: E qual erro ocorreu?

Comment: Não aparece resultado algum

Comment: vc fez o `json_decode` da sua `$response`?

Comment: acabei de fazer json_decode e não consigo trazer somente o valor do código de barras.

Comment: Acho que se usar como array associativo vai ser mais simples... Se o código de barras está sempre no primeiro registro da `titulosEncontrados` vc pode fazer `$response = json_decode($response, true);` e `$codBarras = $response['titulosEncontrados'][0]['cCodigoBarras'];`

Comment: resolvi meu problema de retorna os dados para uma variavel criando um foreach dentro de outro foreach..

Answer (score -1):

Se o payload/body da requisição é um JSON (consegue observar isto no `Content-type: application/json` e o conteúdo (`-d`) inicia por `{`). Então você deve oferecer um JSON:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['call' => 'PesquisarLancamentos', 'app_key' => 'XXXXXXXXX','app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX']));
```

O `json_encode` irá codificar o array para JSON, e ele será enviado como corpo (usando o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`).

Comment: Para quem deu negativo, qual o problema da resposta?